# Centrar elementos con CSS y Bootstrap

Tags: css

Muy buenas tardes para todos donde se encuentren, lo siguiente es para pedirles su ayuda para poder centrar elementos haciendo uso de de CSS y bootstrap, se trata de un formulario de login el cual consta de los típicos input de usuario y contraseña, aclaro que ya cuento con un estilo definido, pero he venido modificando dicho estilo, consiguiendo lo que necesito, lo único que hay por corregir es el elemento de fondo el cual es una clase que da un color de fondo y un tamaño, lo que necesito es ajustar ese fondo al tamaño de las cajas de usuario y contraseña. adjunto código y pantallazo de el formulario login.

```
<form name="f_login" action="index.php?nlogin={$nlogin}" method="post" class="form" role="form">
   <div id="box_login" class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="page-header">
               <h1>
                  <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Iniciar sesión
               </h1>
               <p class="help-block">
                  {if="FS_DEMO"}
                  Bienvenido a la demo de FacturaScripts, escribe tu email para continuar:
                  {else}
                  Debes seleccionar tu usuario e introducir la contraseña para acceder al sistema.
                  {/if}
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="well well-sm">
               <br/>
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail hidden-xs">
                           {if="FS_DEMO"}
                           <img src="{#FS_PATH#}view/img/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
                           {elseif="file_exists(FS_MYDOCS.'images/logo.png')"}
                           <img src="images/logo.png" alt="{$fsc->empresa->nombre}"/>
                           {elseif="file_exists(FS_MYDOCS.'images/logo.jpg')"}
                           <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="{$fsc->empresa->nombre}"/>
                           {else}
                           <img src="{#FS_PATH#}view/img/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
                           {/if}
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                        {if="FS_DEMO"}
                        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="demo"/>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Escribe tu email" required="" autocomplete="off"/>
                        </div>
                        {else}
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input name="user" class="form-control input-lg" onchange="document.f_login.password.focus()" placeholder="Usuario"/>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-lg" maxlength="32" required="" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
                           <p class="help-block">
                              <a href="#" id="b_new_password">¿Has olvidado la contraseña?</a>
                           </p>
                        </div>
                        {/if}
                        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" id="login">
                           <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Iniciar sesión
                        </button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <br/>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es el container que tienes, la clase container intenta tomar el ancho de la pagina

Answer (score 0):

1. Necesitas quitar la clase `container` en el `div` de la clase despues del `div` con clases `well well-sm`
2. hay que ajustar todos los `col-sm-3 col-md-3` solo con `col-md-6 col-sm-6`
3. Hay que agregar 2 div, uno antes y otro despues de las clases `col-md-6 col-sm-6` agregando `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form name="f_login" action="index.php?nlogin={$nlogin}" method="post" class="form" role="form">
   <div id="box_login" class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="page-header">
               <h1>
                  <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Iniciar sesión
               </h1>
               <p class="help-block">
                  {if="FS_DEMO"}
                  Bienvenido a la demo de FacturaScripts, escribe tu email para continuar:
                  {else}
                  Debes seleccionar tu usuario e introducir la contraseña para acceder al sistema.
                  {/if}
               </p>
            </div>
            <div class="well well-sm">
               <br/>
               <div><!-- Quitar container -->
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="thumbnail hidden-xs">
                           {if="FS_DEMO"}
                           <img src="{#FS_PATH#}view/img/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
                           {elseif="file_exists(FS_MYDOCS.'images/logo.png')"}
                           <img src="images/logo.png" alt="{$fsc->empresa->nombre}"/>
                           {elseif="file_exists(FS_MYDOCS.'images/logo.jpg')"}
                           <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="{$fsc->empresa->nombre}"/>
                           {else}
                           <img src="{#FS_PATH#}view/img/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
                           {/if}
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        {if="FS_DEMO"}
                        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="demo"/>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Escribe tu email" required="" autocomplete="off"/>
                        </div>
                        {else}
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input name="user" class="form-control input-lg" onchange="document.f_login.password.focus()" placeholder="Usuario"/>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-lg" maxlength="32" required="" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
                           <p class="help-block">
                              <a href="#" id="b_new_password">¿Has olvidado la contraseña?</a>
                           </p>
                        </div>
                        {/if}
                        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" id="login">
                           <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Iniciar sesión
                        </button>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <br/>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola Rafael Bautista, efectivamente se ajusta, excelente ayuda, pero necesito que los elementos queden de menor tamaño, como se muestra en la imagen, pues de esta forma quedan muy ancho las cajas de texto.

Comment: Es facil solo necesitas agregar 2 div vacios a cada lado para que tome el total de 12 en el sistema de grids

Comment: edité la respuesta

Comment: Hola en que parte se agregarian los DIV?

Comment: en mi respuesta estan como `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>`

Comment: Lo he conseguido, tanto las cajas de texto como la imagen se centran y quedan de menor tamaño, pero el fondo gris (la clase) queda de tamaño más grande.